# fetching image from database to show in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get an image from database to display on the Canvas but it not work. Nothing show on canvas. Cana any one help me.

This is my query code

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "museum"); 

    $sql = "SELECT bgBNPage FROM general "; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array ($result) )
    {
    echo ('<img src="' . $row['bgBNPage'] . ' ">');
  }
?>
```

This is my canvas

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas"  width="236" height="422" style="border:1px solid #000000; position:absolute; top:68px; left:38px;">
  <img id="logo2" src="<?php $row['bgBNPage'] ?>" >
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

This is my database
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not working, because you are putting a `img` element **inside** a `canvas` element, which is not possible, as far as I know.

You could either remove the `canvas`, or use a little javascript, to paint the `image` onto the `canvas`.

Check out my example.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('bgCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="bgCanvas"  width="236" height="422" style="border:1px solid #000000; position:absolute; top:68px; left:38px;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: I can do something similar to this example. I can put any image into canvas but i cannot fetch image from my database to show on canvas. I don't know the syntax of html5 that fetch image from database show in canvas

Comment: As far as I know, there is no XML syntax that you could use to append the image to the canvas. You are forced to use javascript for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yeah support for your first statement would be citing a source like [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas): **Permitted Content** for [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas): "_Transparent but with no [interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content) descendants except for <a> elements, <button> elements, <input> elements whose type attribute is checkbox, radio, or button._" and `<img>` falls into that category of interactive content...